# Does this complex power series converges on the unit circle?

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

Prove that the series $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{[\sqrt n]}}{n}z^n$$ converges on $\partial B(0,1)$.Where $[x]$ implies the greatest integer that is not bigger than $x$.

It is easy to prove that it converges at $z=1$. Actually, rewriting $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{[\sqrt n]}}{n}$$ as $$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k(\frac{1}{k^2}+……+\frac{1}{(k+1)^2-1}) $$ and by the Dirichlet theorem we immediately deduce that the series converges.

But for $z=e^{i\theta}$ it seems hard to prove.

Comment: what's the Dirichlet theorem ?

Comment: @mercio Dirichlet series:For the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n b_n$$,if ${a_n}$ monotonically converges to $0$,$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n b_k$$ is bounded.Then the series converges.

Answer (score 0):

First we prove a lemma.

$Lemma$ If

$(i)$$$\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$$ is bounded;

$(ii)$ $$\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = 0$$

$(iii)$ $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty |b_n-b_{n+1}| \lt \infty$$

Then the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nb_n$$ converges.

Proof:Set $$|\sum_{k=1}^n a_k| \le M$$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z_+}$. Since $$\lim_{n \to \infty}b_n=0$$ and $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty |b_n-b_{n+1}| \lt \infty$$, then by the definition of limit and $Cauchyˊs$ $principle$, for any $\epsilon \gt 0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{Z_+}$, $n \gt N+1$ implies that $|b_n| \lt \frac{\epsilon}{3M}$ and $$|\sum_{k=n}^{n+p}a_k b_k| \lt \frac{\epsilon}{3M}$$ for any $p \in \mathbb{Z_+}$.

By the $Abel$ $identity$ we have $$|\sum_{k=n}^{n+p}a_k b_k| = |\sum_{k=n-1}^{n+p}(\sum_{i=1}^k)(b_k-b_{k+1})+\sum_{k=1}^{n+p}a_k b_{n+p} - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_k b_{n-1}|\le \sum_{k=n-1}^{n+p-1}|\sum_{i=1}^k a_i||b_k-b_{k+1}|+|\sum_{k=1}^{n+p}a_k||b_{n+p}|+|\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_k||b_{n-1}| \le M \frac{\epsilon}{3M} + M \frac{\epsilon}{3M} +M \frac{\epsilon}{3M}=\epsilon$$
, done.

Here we set $a_n=cos n\theta(0 \lt \theta \lt 2\pi)$,$b_n=\frac{(-1)^{\sqrt n}}{n}$.
Easily we compute that $$ |\sum_{k=1}^n cos k\theta| = |\frac{sin(n+\frac{1}{2})\theta - sin \frac{\theta}{2}}{2sin \frac{\theta}{2}}| \le \frac{1}{sin \frac{\theta}{2}}$$ bounded.

Rewrite $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty |(-1)^{\sqrt n}\frac{1}{n}-(-1)^{\sqrt{n+1}}\frac{1}{n+1}| = \sum_{k=1}^\infty(\sum_{n=k^2}^{(k+1)^2-2}(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1})+\frac{1}{(k+1)^2-1}-\frac{1}{(k+1)^2})=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}) \lt \infty$$

By the lemma,we immediately have the conclusion.